# What is memory fragmentation?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, fragmentation

I've heard the term "memory fragmentation" used a few times in the context of C++ dynamic memory allocation.  I've found some questions about how to deal with memory fragmentation, but can't find a direct question that deals with it itself.  So:

- What is memory fragmentation?
- How can I tell if memory fragmentation is a problem for my application?  What kind of program is most likely to suffer?
- What are good common ways to deal with memory fragmentation?

Also:

- I've heard using dynamic allocations a lot can increase memory fragmentation.  Is this true?  In the context of C++, I understand all the standard containers (std::string, std::vector, etc) use dynamic memory allocation.  If these are used throughout a program (especially std::string), is memory fragmentation more likely to be a problem?
- How can memory fragmentation be dealt with in an STL-heavy application?

Comment: There are already plenty of great answers, but here's some pictures from an actual application (Firefox) where memory fragmentation was a big problem: http://blog.pavlov.net/2007/11/10/memory-fragmentation/

Comment: Below is an updated location for the links posted by Marius:https://pavlovdotnet.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/memory-fragmentation/

Comment: [Yet another link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120101120625/http://blog.pavlov.net:80/2007/11/10/memory-fragmentation/)

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Imagine that you have a "large" (32 bytes) expanse of free memory:

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
----------------------------------
```

Now, allocate some of it (5 allocations):

```
----------------------------------
|aaaabbccccccddeeee              |
----------------------------------
```

Now, free the first four allocations but not the fifth:

```
----------------------------------
|              eeee              |
----------------------------------
```

Now, try to allocate 16 bytes. Oops, I can't, even though there's nearly double that much free.

On systems with virtual memory, fragmentation is less of a problem than you might think, because large allocations only need to be contiguous in *virtual* address space, not in *physical* address space. So in my example, if I had virtual memory with a page size of 2 bytes then I could make my 16 byte allocation with no problem. Physical memory would look like this:

```
----------------------------------
|ffffffffffffffeeeeff            |
----------------------------------
```

whereas virtual memory (being much bigger) could look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------...
|              eeeeffffffffffffffff                   
------------------------------------------------------...
```

The classic symptom of memory fragmentation is that you try to allocate a large block and you can't, even though you appear to have enough memory free. Another possible consequence is the inability of the process to release memory back to the OS (because each of the large blocks it has allocated from the OS, for `malloc` etc. to sub-divide, has something left in it, even though most of each block is now unused).

Tactics to prevent memory fragmentation in C++ work by allocating objects from different areas according to their size and/or their expected lifetime. So if you're going to create a lot of objects and destroy them all together later, allocate them from a memory pool. Any other allocations you do in between them won't be from the pool, hence won't be located in between them in memory, so memory will not be fragmented as a result. Or, if you're going to allocate a lot of objects of the same size then allocate them from the same pool. Then a stretch of free space in the pool can never be smaller than the size you're trying to allocate from that pool.

Generally you don't need to worry about it much, unless your program is long-running and does a lot of allocation and freeing. It's when you have mixtures of short-lived and long-lived objects that you're most at risk, but even then `malloc` will do its best to help. Basically, ignore it until your program has allocation failures or unexpectedly causes the system to run low on memory (catch this in testing, for preference!).

The standard libraries are no worse than anything else that allocates memory, and standard containers all have an `Alloc` template parameter which you could use to fine-tune their allocation strategy if absolutely necessary.

Comment: So each character is a byte? Which would make your "large expanse" == 32 bytes (I'm guessing -- didn't count) :) Nice example, but mentioning the units before the last line would be helpful. :)

Comment: @jalf: Yep. I wasn't going to mention units at all, then realised at the end I had to. Was working on it while you were commenting.

Comment: It was pretty hard to choose an "answer" - lots of great answers here and I'd encourage anyone interested to read all of them.  Still, I think you covered all the important points here.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation, although for the virtual memory example, a slightly larger page size (say 6) would probably make it slightly clearer how the page size affects the end result.

Comment: "The standard libraries are no worse than anything else that allocates memory". That would be nice if true, but implementations of standard C++ templates such as string & vector can have some highly undesirable behaviours when they resize. For example in older versions of visual studio the std::string basically resizes by realloc 1.5 * current_size (to the nearest 8 bytes). So if you keep appending to a string you can anhilate the heap very easily, especially on embedded systems. The best defence is to reserve the amount of space you anticipate using to avoid hidden reallocs.

Comment: So the virtual memory is still fragmented? How does that help?

Comment: @du369: The virtual memory isn't fragmented anything like as badly as the physical is. `ffffffffffffffff` is a contiguous allocation in virtual memory, but no such contiguous allocation can exist in physical memory. If you prefer to look at it that they're equally fragmented, but virtual space is much larger, then feel free to look at it that way instead. The important practical point is that using vast virtual address spaces is often enough to be able to ignore fragmentation, so it helps whenever it allows me to make my 16 byte allocation.

Answer (score 102):

> **What is memory fragmentation?**

Memory fragmentation is when most of your memory is allocated in a large number of non-contiguous blocks, or chunks - leaving a good percentage of your total memory unallocated, but unusable for most typical scenarios. This results in out of memory exceptions, or allocation errors (i.e. malloc returns null).

The easiest way to think about this is to imagine you have a big empty wall that you need to put pictures *of varying sizes* on. Each picture takes up a certain size and you obviously can't split it into smaller pieces to make it fit. You need an empty spot on the wall, the size of the picture, or else you can't put it up. Now, if you start hanging pictures on the wall and you're not careful about how you arrange them, you will soon end up with a wall that's partially covered with pictures and even though you may have empty spots most new pictures won't fit because they're larger than the available spots. You can still hang really small pictures, but most ones won't fit. So you'll have to re-arrange (compact) the ones already on the wall to make room for more..

Now, imagine that the wall is your (heap) memory  and the pictures are objects.. That's memory fragmentation..

**How can I tell if memory fragmentation is a problem for my application?  What kind of program is most likely to suffer?**

A telltale sign that you may be dealing with memory fragmentation is if you get many allocation errors, especially when the percentage of used memory is high - but not you haven't yet used up all the memory - so technically you should have plenty of room for the objects you are trying to allocate.

When memory is heavily fragmented, memory allocations will likely take longer because the memory allocator has to do more work to find a suitable space for the new object. If in turn you have many memory allocations (which you probably do since you ended up with memory fragmentation) the allocation time may even cause noticeable delays.

**What are good common ways to deal with memory fragmentation?**

Use a good algorithm for allocating memory. Instead of allocating memory for a lot of small objects, pre-allocate memory for a contiguous array of those smaller objects. Sometimes being a little wasteful when allocating memory can go along way for performance and may save you the trouble of having to deal with memory fragmentation.

Comment: +1. I just deleted my proposed answer becasue your "pictures on the wall" metaphor is really, really a good, clear one.

Comment: I would like it more if you emphasized the fact that the pictures must have varying sizes. Otherwise, no fragmentation will happen.

Comment: Interestingly, [main memory databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) are becoming somewhat practical these days (with really much memory being available). In this context it is worth noting that, as for HDDs, reading continuous lines from RAM is much faster than if the data is fragmented.

Comment: Nice visual analogy with the pictures on the walls, but main memory isn't two dimensional!  Still, nice answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Memory fragmentation is the same concept as disk fragmentation: it refers to space being wasted because the areas in use are not packed closely enough together.

Suppose for a simple toy example that you have ten bytes of memory:

```
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Now let's allocate three three-byte blocks, name A, B, and C:

```
 | A | A | A | B | B | B | C | C | C |   |
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Now deallocate block B:

```
 | A | A | A |   |   |   | C | C | C |   |
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Now what happens if we try to allocate a four-byte block D? Well, we have four bytes of memory free, but we don't have four *contiguous* bytes of memory free, so we can't allocate D! This is inefficient use of memory, because we should have been able to store D, but we were unable to. And we can't move C to make room, because very likely some variables in our program are pointing at C, and we can't automatically find and change all of these values.

How do you know it's a problem? Well, the biggest sign is that your program's virtual memory size is considerably larger than the amount of memory you're actually using. In a real-world example, you would have many more than ten bytes of memory, so D would just get allocated starting a byte 9, and bytes 3-5 would remain unused unless you later allocated something three bytes long or smaller.

In this example, 3 bytes is not a whole lot to waste, but consider a more pathological case where two allocations of a a couple of bytes are, for example, ten megabytes apart in memory, and you need to allocate a block of size 10 megabytes + 1 byte. You have to go ask the OS for over ten megabytes more virtual memory to do that, even though you're just one byte shy of having enough space already.

How do you prevent it? The worst cases tend to arise when you frequently create and destroy small objects, since that tends to produce a "swiss cheese" effect with many small objects separated by many small holes, making it impossible to allocate larger objects in those holes. When you know you're going to be doing this, an effective strategy is to pre-allocate a large block of memory as a pool for your small objects, and then manually manage the creation of the small objects within that block, rather than letting the default allocator handle it.

In general, the fewer allocations you do, the less likely memory is to get fragmented. However, STL deals with this rather effectively. If you have a string which is using the entirety of its current allocation and you append one character to it, it doesn't simply re-allocate to its current length plus one, it *doubles* its length. This is a variation on the "pool for frequent small allocations" strategy. The string is grabbing a large chunk of memory so that it can deal efficiently with repeated small increases in size without doing repeated small reallocations. All STL containers in fact do this sort of thing, so generally you won't need to worry too much about fragmentation caused by automatically-reallocating STL containers.

Although of course STL containers don't pool memory *between* each other, so if you're going to create many small containers (rather than a few containers that get resized frequently) you may have to concern yourself with preventing fragmentation in the same way you would for any frequently-created small objects, STL or not.

Answer (score 14):

> - What is memory fragmentation?

Memory fragmentation is the problem of memory becoming unusable even though it is theoretically available. There are two kinds of fragmentation: *internal fragmentation* is memory that is allocated but cannot be used (e.g. when memory is allocated in 8 byte chunks but the program repeatedly does single allocations when it needs only 4 bytes). *external fragmentation* is the problem of free memory becoming divided into many small chunks so that large allocation requests cannot be met although there is enough overall free memory.

> - How can I tell if memory fragmentation is a problem for my application? What kind of program is most likely to suffer?

memory fragmentation is a problem if your program uses much more system memory than its actual paylod data would require (and you've ruled out memory leaks).

> - What are good common ways to deal with memory fragmentation?

Use a good memory allocator. IIRC, those that use a "best fit" strategy are generally much superior at avoiding fragmentation, if a little slower. However, it has also been shown that for any allocation strategy, there are pathological worst cases. Fortunately, the typical allocation patterns of most applications are actually relatively benign for the allocators to handle. There's a bunch of papers out there if you're interested in the details:

- Paul R. Wilson, Mark S. Johnstone, Michael Neely and David Boles. Dynamic Storage Allocation: A Survey and Critical Review. In Proceedings of the 1995
  International Workshop on Memory Management, Springer Verlag LNCS, 1995
- Mark S.Johnstone, Paul R. Wilson. The Memory Fragmentation Problem: Solved?
  In ACM SIG-PLAN Notices, volume 34 No. 3, pages 26-36, 1999
- M.R. Garey, R.L. Graham and J.D. Ullman. Worst-Case analysis of memory allocation algorithms. In Fourth Annual ACM Symposium on the Theory of Computing, 1972

Comment: nice. are these papers free to access.

Comment: @rsonx: formally no (I think), but when I worked on this topic (almost 20 years ago), I was able to find free copies online.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** 
[**Google TCMalloc: Thread-Caching Malloc**](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) 
It has been found that **it is quite good at handling fragmentation** in a long running process.

---

I have been developing a server application that had problems with memory fragmentation on HP-UX 11.23/11.31 ia64.

It looked like this. There was a process that made memory allocations and deallocations and ran for days. And even though there were no memory leaks memory consumption of the process kept increasing.

About my experience. On HP-UX it is very easy to find memory fragmentation using HP-UX gdb. You set a break-point and when you hit it you run this command: `info heap` and see all memory allocations for the process and the total size of heap. Then your continue your program and then some time later your again hit the break-point. You do again `info heap`. If the total size of heap is bigger but the number and the size of separate allocations are the same then it is likely that you have memory allocation problems. If necessary do this check few fore times.

My way of improving the situation was this. After I had done some analysis with HP-UX gdb I saw that memory problems were caused by the fact that I used `std::vector` for storing some types of information from a database. `std::vector` requires that its data must be kept in one block. I had a few containers based on `std::vector`. These containers were regularly recreated. There were often situations when new records were added to the database and after that the containers were recreated. And since the recreated containers were bigger their did not fit into available blocks of free memory and the runtime asked for a new bigger block from the OS. As a result even though there were no memory leaks the memory consumption of the process grew. I improved the situation when I changed the containers. Instead of `std::vector` I started using `std::deque` which has a different way of allocating memory for data.

I know that one of ways to avoid memory fragmentation on HP-UX is to use either Small Block Allocator or use MallocNextGen. On RedHat Linux the default allocator seems to handle pretty well allocating of a lot of small blocks. On Windows there is `Low-fragmentation Heap` and it adresses the problem of large number of small allocations.

My understanding is that in an STL-heavy application you have first to identify problems. Memory allocators (like in libc) actually handle the problem of a lot of small allocations, which is typical for `std::string` (for instance in my server application there are lots of STL strings but as I see from running `info heap` they are not causing  any problems). My impression is that you need to avoid frequent large allocations. Unfortunately there are situations when you can't avoid them and have to change your code. As I say in my case I improved the situation when switched to `std::deque`. If you identify your memory fragmention it might be possible to talk about it more precisely.

Answer (score 6):

Memory fragmentation is most likely to occur when you allocate and *deallocate* many objects of varying sizes. Suppose you have the following layout in memory:

```
obj1 (10kb) | obj2(20kb) | obj3(5kb) | unused space (100kb)
```

Now, when `obj2` is released, you have 120kb of unused memory, but you cannot allocate a full block of 120kb, because the memory is fragmented.

Common techniques to avoid that effect include [ring buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) and [object pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). In the context of the STL, methods like [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) can help.

Answer (score 6):

A very detailed answer on memory fragmentation can be found here.

http://library.softwareverify.com/memory-fragmentation-your-worst-nightmare/

This is the culmination of 11 years of memory fragmentation answers I have been providing to people asking me questions about memory fragmentation at softwareverify.com

Answer (score 3):

> What is memory fragmentation?

When your app uses dynamic memory, it allocates and frees chunks of memory. In the beginning, the whole memory space of your app is one contiguous block of free memory. However, when you allocate and free blocks of different size, the memory starts to get *fragmented*, i.e. instead of a big contiguous free block and a number of contiguous allocated blocks, there will be a allocated and free blocks mixed up. Since the free blocks have limited size, it is difficult to reuse them. E.g. you may have 1000 bytes of free memory, but can't allocate memory for a 100 byte block, because all the free blocks are at most 50 bytes long.

Another, unavoidable, but less problematic source of fragmentation is that in most architectures, memory addresses must be *aligned* to 2, 4, 8 etc. byte boundaries (i.e. the addresses must be multiples of 2, 4, 8 etc.) This means that even if you have e.g. a struct containing 3 `char` fields, your struct may have a size of 12 instead of 3, due to the fact that each field is aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

> How can I tell if memory fragmentation is a problem for my application? What kind of program is most likely to suffer?

The obvious answer is that you get an out of memory exception.

Apparently there is no good portable way to detect memory fragmentation in C++ apps. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453568/portable-way-to-detect-heap-fragmentation-in-c-at-runtime) for more details.

> What are good common ways to deal with memory fragmentation?

It is difficult in C++, since you use direct memory addresses in pointers, and you have no control over who references a specific memory address. So rearranging the allocated memory blocks (the way the Java garbage collector does) is not an option.

A custom allocator may help by managing the allocation of small objects in a bigger chunk of memory, and reusing the free slots within that chunk.

Answer (score 3):

This is a super-simplified version for dummies.

As objects get created in memory, they get added to the end of the used portion in memory.

If an object that is not at the end of the used portion of memory is deleted, meaning this object was in between 2 other objects, it will create a "hole".

This is what's called fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to add an item on the heap what happens is that the computer has to do a search for space to fit that item.  That's why dynamic allocations when not done on a memory pool or with a pooled allocator can "slow" things down.  For a heavy STL application if you're doing multi-threading there is the [Hoard allocator](http://www.hoard.org/) or the [TBB Intel](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) version.

Now, when memory is fragmented two things can occur:

1. There will have to be more searches to find a good space to stick "large" objects.  That is, with many small objects scattered about finding a nice contigous chunk of memory could under certain conditions be difficult (these are extreme.)
2. Memory is not some easily read entity.  Processors are limited to how much they can hold and where.  They do this by swapping pages if an item they need is one place but the current addresses are another.  If you are constantly having to swap pages, processing can slow down (again, extreme scenarios where this impacts performance.)  See this posting on [virtual memory](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/virtual-memory.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Memory fragmentation occurs because memory blocks of different sizes are requested. Consider a buffer of 100 bytes. You request two chars, then an integer. Now you free the two chars, then request a new integer- but that integer can't fit in the space of the two chars. That memory cannot be re-used because it is not in a large enough contiguous block to re-allocate. On top of that, you've invoked a lot of allocator overhead for your chars.

Essentially, memory only comes in blocks of a certain size on most systems. Once you split these blocks up, they cannot be rejoined until the whole block is freed. This can lead to whole blocks in use when actually only a small part of the block is in use.

The primary way to reduce heap fragmentation is to make larger, less frequent allocations. In the extreme, you can use a managed heap that is capable of moving objects, at least, within your own code. This completely eliminates the problem - from a memory perspective, anyway. Obviously moving objects and such has a cost. In reality, you only really have a problem if you are allocating very small amounts off the heap often. Using contiguous containers (vector, string, etc) and allocating on the stack as much as humanly possible (always a good idea for performance) is the best way to reduce it. This also increases cache coherence, which makes your application run faster.

What you should remember is that on a 32bit x86 desktop system, you have an entire 2GB of memory, which is split into 4KB "pages" (pretty sure the page size is the same on all x86 systems). You will have to invoke some omgwtfbbq fragmentation to have a problem. Fragmentation really is an issue of the past, since modern heaps are excessively large for the vast majority of applications, and there's a prevalence of systems that are capable of withstanding it, such as managed heaps.

Answer (score 0):

> **What kind of program is most likely to suffer?**

A nice (=horrifying) example for the problems associated with memory fragmentation was the development and release of **"Elemental: War of Magic"**, a computer game by [Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/).

The game was built for 32bit/2GB Memory and had to do a lot of optimisation in memory management to make the game work within those 2GB of Memory. As the "optimisation" lead to constant allocation and de-allocation, over time heap memory fragmentation occurred and made the game crash *every* *time*.

There is a ["war story" interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zD33Hrbo4Y) on YouTube.