# Virtual destructor Arduino Due undefined reference to operator delete

Tags: c++

When an interface contains a pure virtual method, it is recommended to use a virtual destructor. So for example, I have this code:

```
    template
    class A {
    protected:
        char buffer[Size];
    public:
        virtual void method() = 0;
        A() = default;
        virtual ~A() = default;
    };

    template
    class B : public A {
    public:
        void method() override;
        B() = default
        ~B() = default;
    };

    int main() {
        B b;
        b.method();
    }
```

But when I try to compile this with g++ for an Arduino Due, I get the following error:

```
    main.cpp:(.text._ZN4r2d29robot_arm22uarm_gcode_generator_cILj100EED0Ev[_ZN4r2d29robot_arm22uarm_gcode_generator_cILj100EED5Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
```

However, when I remove the destructor from A entirely, it removes the error, but wouldn't this cause Undifed Behaviour? Also, when I just remove the virtual keyword from the destructor of A it gives me the same error message.

Comment: Are You linking against an implementation of the C++ standard library? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7015285/1116364

Comment: Note that if I just copy and paste your code into the Arduino Web Editor (after fixing the typos), it compiles just fine there…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather strange that the sole presence of a destructor would introduce a reference to the global `operator delete`. However, it seems that you're not the first one with this problem: [Undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015285/undefined-reference-to-operator-deletevoid). As pointed out in the comments there, the C++ standard library is [not really available](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus) on `avr-g++` which is most likely what you're using as well.

All that being said, however, I believe I can offer some relief.

> When an interface contains a pure virtual method, it is recommended to use a virtual destructor.

A virtual destructor is only necessary when you need to `delete` an object via a base pointer [[expr.delete]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3). Think of a virtual destructor as part of the interface itself. If an interface declares a virtual destructor, that means "objects that implement this interface can be deleted". The operation `delete` becomes part of the interface.

If you do not need the capability to `delete` as part of your interface, which, I would argue, should actually be the default, then you don't need a virtual destructor. Simply declare the destructor non-virtual and make it protected. Thus, you remove the operation `delete` from the interface and pass on the decision whether a type can be deleted further down to more concrete implementations of the interface…