# Virtual memory size increasing in a program C++

Tags: c++, linux

I have a program which is working perfectly fine. But it works fine for 5-6 days after that it gets killed `SIGKILL`. When I observed that memory was the issue, I did strict deallocation wherever allocation is done.

I am using linux `top` command for monitoring the memory usage.

As of now the program is working fine. But, slowly the `VIRT` virtual memory attribute in `top` command is increasing slowly. Why is that so? I am deallocating stuff everywhere it is needed.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: "I am deallocating stuff everywhere it is needed." if that is true, then your program just /needs/ more memory over the time, however I do not believe that this is true and you should run it through some leak checker.

Comment: there are memory-leaks in your program. use **valgrind** to find memory-leaks.

Comment: @PlasmaHH "program just /needs/ more memory over the time". What does that mean? Anyways I m deallocating memory once allocated know. Then the memory consumption shouldn't happen right ?

Comment: It is SIGKILL not SIGKELL, so I edited it

Comment: @Chaitanya: Why do you allocate memory when you deallocate it right away? You surely have some datastructures that contain elements over the runtime of the program that get changed/added to, and for those you surely need memory. If you dont have them, you could replace all your memory allocate by stack objects...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Ok. Yes, I have data structures that contain elements over runtime and once I use them, I deallocate them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are developing on Linux, compile your application with `g++ -Wall -g`, improve it till no warnings are given, and use `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug the memory leaks.

You might be perhaps interested in using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Read also about [memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3770457/841108).

Comment: beat me to it, use valgrind, (also ensure -O0) and use the `--leak-check=full` in valgrind (I would however be vastly in favour of fixing the program rather than adding a GC).

Answer (score 1):

You may check any memory mismanagement with [valgrind](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/)

Try to run the application for a while and check any possible memory problem.