# C - Freeing memory after strdup()

Tags: c, memory

I'm doing a lesson from the *Learn C the Hard way* online course.  In the code sample below, I don't understand why the two `free()` calls are necessary.  I thought one would only need to call `free()` once, because only one `malloc()` occurs.  Could somebody clarify why we need two?

If I comment out `free(who->name);` then `valgrind` tells me that I've lost a chunk 'o memory, like so;

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 21 bytes in 2 blocks
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
{
    assert(who != NULL);

    free(who->name); /* Why this one??! */
    free(who);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // make two people structures
    struct Person *joe = Person_create(
            "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

    struct Person *frank = Person_create(
            "Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180);

    // destroy them both so we clean up
    Person_destroy(joe);
    Person_destroy(frank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because also strdup() allocates memory then it must be freed (see [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)).

Comment: `who->name = strdup(name);` here you allocate memory i.e. strdup() allocates.

Comment: `strdup` is a `malloc` in disguise.

Comment: Reading the documentation of a standard function is *faster* than asking on SO !

Comment: So the memory strdup() allocates isn't freed when you free(who)?

Comment: How else is `who->name` going to be freed? Ask yourself who is going to do that automatically for you? How can the compiler know that `who->name` is the final reference to the memory. After all, if the struct isn't freed automatically, why should the string be>

Comment: @Andy P: No. You need a separate `free` for every separate `malloc`. And `strdup` is a `malloc`.

Comment: No, it's not. Each free() deallocates memory allocated by one malloc. If you allocate space for a struct with pointers to many other structs then each one must be deallocated separately (same, for example, when you have an array of arrays).

Comment: `strdup` is not a Standard C function, however it is in POSIX.  (No Standard C functions return a pointer that requires freeing, other than  `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`).

Comment: a standard function can be mentioned in some other standard than C99. Posix is such a standard.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Nobody said `strdup` is a Standard *C* function. It just a C function, and a standard function ;-). Anyway, I agree it's important to remember that non-POSIX C environments often don't have it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) is *documented* as

> ```
>   The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a
>   duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained
>   with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).
> ```

<sup>BTW, as [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) commented, `strdup` is standard in Posix, not in the C99 language specification.</sup>

Of course `free` only releases the memory zone that you pass it (it does not magically and indirectly free any zone pointed inside the memory zone you pass it). Again, [free(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) says:

> ```
>   The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc().  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called
>   before, undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is
>   performed.
> ```

Read much more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). If you don't like that, learn about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). With C on Linux and some other systems, you could consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). You'll then use `GC_MALLOC` and/or `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC` instead of `malloc`, and `GC_STRDUP` instead of `strdup` and you won't bother about `free` (you might sometimes use `GC_FREE` if wanted). I find it very useful, but it does have some drawbacks (a bit slower than `malloc`, and no explicit guarantee about releasing memory...).

Read about [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption), and [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

BTW, you should first compile your program with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Then you could use your debugger (`gdb`), set a breakpoint in `malloc` after `main` has been reached, and see when `malloc` is called. You'll see that  `strdup` is calling `malloc` ....

---

FYI, on Linux, `malloc` is implemented using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -and sometimes the old [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)- syscalls -to get "large" memory regions (of several kilobytes or even megabytes),  and `free` may sometimes call [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) -for these large regions- but most often it justs mark a freed block as reusable, so that block could be reused in some *future* calls to `malloc`. Hence a program doing `malloc` and `free` might not release all it previously used memory to the kernel. See also [this question about *memory fragmentation*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3770457/841108).

### use also [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

On *some* operating systems (e.g. Linux) you could compile your C code (using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the `valgrind` tool at runtime. It slows down the execution, but it is helpful in finding bugs like *some* memory leaks and *some* [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). With a recent GCC or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler, you could also use -at compile time- [its address sanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) (instrumenting the generated code).

You might also read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/), related to memory allocation and garbage collection algorithms.