# How to release rails server memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I am using Thin server with 2 processes.

When request grows up, my vps server memory will grows up too.

The problem is:

When server is idle, the thin server memory not cut down, it remain the high memory usage.

I wanna know:

- How's the memory has been used? (establish a connection, ActiveRecord query...or whatever)
- Why Thin not release memory?
- It is Rails's problem or Thin's, or Both?

Comment: See also: [What is memory fragmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770457/what-is-memory-fragmentation)

Comment: This is a really good article to read https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/performance