# Why can libuv's threadpool lead to unrecoverable and catastrophic memory fragmentation?

Tags: node.js, libuv

The documentation [for Node's zlib library](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_threadpool_usage) says:

> All zlib APIs, except those that are explicitly synchronous, use libuv's threadpool. This can lead to surprising effects in some applications, such as subpar performance (which can be mitigated by adjusting the pool size) and/or **unrecoverable and catastrophic memory fragmentation**.

Quite a thing to throw in there with no further explanation! What are they talking about?

Comment: I assume you're not asking what memory fragmentation is, but rather how it occurs from the usage of libuv's threadpool. Just in case, though: [What is memory fragmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3770457/1541563)

Comment: Yes - see the title of this question.

Comment: > Because of how some operating systems handle memory allocation and deallocation, this may lead to to significant memory fragmentation

Comment: Ok but why? Does this mean that I can't use the API? It's all very vague.